How do men of faith separate good miracles from bad miracles?
The most standard problem of miracles, attacked by Christian apologists, is that miracles break the immutable laws of physics, and therefore by definition are logically impossible. This was put forward best by David Hume. Many Christian apologists address and possibly rebute this, in various ways.
But what about the second-order problem of miracles?
That is, let's grant that the Creator and wonderworkers intervene in the laws of nature. How, then, do you guarantee that you get the right type of miracles and avoid the wrong type of miracles?
That is, how do you get the happy miracles like Elisha filling the widows jars with superabundant oil, and avoid the unhappy miracles like turning into a halite formation?
Every Christian who believes in miracles seems to be bent that they'll be something good, like getting an incurable cancer healed. But how does the Christian get these joyous miracles without also opening the possibility that they could accidentally turn someone to stone as a result? Why do faith pastors rejoice that they can multiply food but don't fear that they'll literally turn their son into a literal sheep?
It sounds silly, but it's difficult to imagine a world where you allow only good energies to pour from Heaven (which is what all faithful Christians really want) without also allowing for evil energies from Greek mythology to flow from Gehenna.
What is your reflection?

Asking for a 'reflection' is asking for opinion. (Which is off-topic.) One may ask for substantiated evidence of certain behaviour or doctrine among self-professing 'Christians'. Or one may ask for biblical evidence of such. But the above is anecdotal and invites opinion.

@NigelJ It sounds like the natural follow-up question to "can miracles happen" is "how do you discern which miracles are good and which miracles are evil"? Perhaps the fact that I used the emotional words "happy" and "unhappy" caused you to perceive this as opinion-based.

"but it's difficult to imagine a world where you allow only good energies to pour from Heaven (which is what all faithful Christians really want) without also allowing for evil energies from Greek mythology to flow from Gehenna." Well yeah. That has nothing to do with Christianity at all. Miracles aren't a result of any energy flowing from anywhere...

The plagues of Egypt in Exodus seem proof enough that the Bible has plenty of "bad" miracles.

@curiousdannii How do you admit for miracles without also accepting the possibility that Greek mythology might be true as well? Ovid has plenty examples of the gods turning people into stones or trees

There is no guarantee and the Bible teaches that.
In the Books of Exodus and Numbers, the people complained to God (or to Moses, which works out about the same) for food. In the former, God blew in a lot of quail, which the people ate. In the latter (Numbers 11), the people were still grumbling, despite all God's generosity. This time he sent quail, but as the people ate it, a plague broke out.
The sending of diseased quail was a miracle. The people got what they prayed for but also what God knew they deserved.
The plague was evil, but it wasn't. It was evil in that it caused suffering  and death, but it was good in that its purpose was to judge and discipline the people and turn away from sin. So God never causes evil by executing malicious actions against innocents.
This is not an isolated incident with God. When I was younger, I prayed extensively for wisdom. At one point, I went completely deaf in my left ear. After a month on steroids, there was no improvement. I went into the waiting room at the doctor's office after he told me I would probably not get my hearing back, since he could not find the cause of my hearing loss.
While I waited for him to schedule a follow up visit, I took out my Bible. I had a little card with a daily Bible reading schedule. For that day in January, 2005, the reading was from Exodus 4, where Moses has just protested that he is not eloquent, so send someone else.

Then the Lord said to him, “Who has made man's mouth? Who makes him
mute, or deaf, or seeing, or blind? Is it not I, the Lord? Now
therefore go, and I will be with your mouth and teach you what you
shall speak.” (Exodus 4:11-12)

On reading those words, I knew what the doctor did not: God had made me deaf. I also knew that the Lord was in the room with me, speaking the truth to me, and so I was at peace. Trusting that He had a good plan for me, I stopped praying for the healing of my ear.
Two days later, I got my hearing back. The difference was, I had also heard wisdom from God. He had told me that I was spiritually deaf. Despite praying for wisdom all those years, I was not listening to the things God was already telling me. That began a change in me. I made greater efforts to listen and act on what He was telling me.
I think that God making a person deaf when what they want to do is hear from Him qualifies as a "bad miracle". In the end, it resulted in good, but at the time, it felt anything but good.

This is simply crazy.

@Fomalhaut Do note that God is entirely in control of all of these miracles. There's no evil energy involved.

@curiousdannii It's still simply crazy.

@Fomalhaut What about it is so crazy?

@curiousdannii Let's say that you have empathy as a core value. Also you might not know this, but all core values have a fantasy associated with them, and the fantasy of empaths is turning into an animal. If what you say is true, then there is a non-zero probability that an empath might provoke the Creator into turning him into an animal as a "bad miracle". It is not possible to believe this and remain sane.

@Fomalhaut I agree. Because it's not true that the fantasy of empaths is to turn into an animal, and it's also not true that God acts in random or capricious ways. That's how the Greek gods acted, but it has nothing to do with Christianity.

@curiousdannii Please pardon me, but this is too hard to understand for my little peabrain.

@Fomalhaut You seem to be bringing a lot of ideas that aren't from the Bible, and then asking how the Bible's/Christianity's perspective could be anything but crazy. Christians of course do the reverse - start with the Bible, and use it to evaluate ideas from outside the Bible. How are you more certain about empaths wanting to become animals than you are that God is loving and not capricious?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
